# Fetching Images of places from wikipedia

Tags: php, wikipedia-api

I'm Using the following code to fetch images from wikipedia api but at the moment it is giving me random images on that keyword like if I search "spain " it will give me random images with word spain but I need the images of places in spain like we get in wikipedia.
Can any one help me with that?

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search">
    
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<?php
if(@$_GET['search']){
    function get_wiki_image( $search, $limit) {

  $streamContext = array(
    "ssl" => array(
          "verify_peer" => false,
          "verify_peer_name" => false,
      ),
  );

  $url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/';
  $url .= '/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=allimages&aifrom=' . $search . '&ailimit=' . $limit;

  $context = stream_context_create($streamContext);

  if(FALSE === ($content = @file_get_contents($url, false,$context)) ) {
    return false;
  } else {
    $data = json_decode($content,true);
    $ret = array();
    foreach($data['query']['allimages'] as $img) {
      $ret[] = $img['url'];
    }
    return $ret;
  }

}

$search = ucwords($_GET['search']);
$images = get_wiki_image($search,500);

foreach($images as $img) {
  echo "<img src='{$img}' height='50' width='50'>";
}

}



?>
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what your desired result is. What _do_ you expect when you search for `spain`? _"images of places in spain like we get in wikipedia"_ is not a precise description for an api result set.

Comment: Like when you search "Barcelona" in wikipedia it gives pictures of the city on right section I want those pictures." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcelona" if you go on this link you can see there are pictures of the city on the right side  I want those

Comment: That entirely depends on the design of the API and the type of image metadata they store (and expose through the API). Look through the documentation if they support fetching images tied to a specific article.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PageImages API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageImages#API) for this purpose. Generally, it returns you the first image in an article, however, depending on the configurations of Wikipedia it might return a different image in some cases.

To get for example the image of the "Barcelona" article, call https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=Barcelona&piprop=original.

If you need the picture in a certain size, you can also call https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=Barcelona&pithumbsize=250.